dplyr summarize: complete() and .drop=F will not work for filtered data; want to keep 0 counts
I have a dataset with a value, month, and year. I want to count the number of times the value is >= something, let's say 2000, within only the month of June for each year. The issue is that I have a larger dataset with ~100 years of data, and using .drop=F is not working. I have also used complete() and that does also not work. How can I also add the years where the count is 0?
I have looked at the following other posts on stackoverflow and they have not solved my issue:
dplyr summarise: Equivalent of ".drop=FALSE" to keep groups with zero length in output
R group by show count of all factor levels even when zero dplyr
Proper idiom for adding zero count rows in tidyr/dplyr
The code I have been using is:
swan_gtequal95 <- data.frame(data%>%
  filter(month %in% c("06")) %>%
  filter(val  >= 2000) %>%
  group_by(year,.drop=F) %>%
  summarize(winterfloodfreq = n()))

     val year month
1   1840 1922    05
2   1860 1922    05
3   1950 1922    05
4   2020 1922    05
5   2100 1922    05
6   2220 1922    05
7   2220 1922    05
8   2220 1922    05
9   2220 1922    05
10  2170 1922    05
11  2100 1922    05
12  1980 1922    05
13  1900 1922    05
14  1840 1922    05
15  1880 1922    05
16  1950 1922    05
17  2120 1922    05
18  2850 1922    05
19  3480 1922    05
20  4100 1922    05
21  4420 1922    05
22  4530 1922    05
23  4400 1922    05
24  4070 1922    05
25  3870 1923    05
26  4110 1923    05
27  4480 1923    05
28  4450 1923    05
29  4100 1923    05
30  3630 1923    05
31  3270 1923    05
32  3140 1922    06
33  3180 1922    06
34  3390 1922    06
35  3780 1922    06
36  4370 1922    06
37  4960 1922    06
38  5330 1922    06
39  5440 1922    06
40  5280 1922    06
41  5030 1922    06
42  4750 1922    06
43  4450 1922    06
44  4370 1922    06
45  4310 1923    06
46  4270 1923    06
47  4160 1923    06
48  4050 1923    06
49  3970 1923    06
50  3830 1923    06
51  3690 1923    06
52  3460 1923    06
53  3390 1922    06
54  3280 1922    06
55  3030 1922    06
56  2820 1922    06
57  2580 1922    06
58  2350 1922    06
59  2220 1922    06
60  2120 1922    06
61  2040 1922    06
62  1980 1922    07
63  1900 1922    07
64  1840 1922    07
65  1750 1922    07
66  1670 1922    07
67  1630 1922    07
68  1580 1922    07
69  1510 1922    07
70  1570 1922    07
71  1530 1923    07
72  1480 1923    07
73  1410 1923    07
74  1340 1923    07
75  1230 1922    07
76  1170 1923    07
77  1110 1923    07
78  1090 1923    07
79  1050 1923    07
80  1020 1923    07
81   975 1923    07
82   950 1922    07
83   933 1922    07
84   900 1922    07
85   892 1922    07
86   860 1922    07
87   876 1922    07
88   852 1922    07


.drop= has to do with group columns that are factors, it isn't clear if any of your data is like this. I can get what I think you're going for with either quux |> filter(month %in% c(5), val >= 2000) |> count(year) or replacing count(.) with summarize(.by = year, n = n()). If these don't work, please update your question with expected output given this sample data. (Notable is that your sample data doesn't have any of c("12", "01", "02"), and the column name is val, not value as your code suggests.)

I ended up using mutate on the dataset initially and then pass through summarize in dplyr to solve my problem. Of note: this did insert 0's for years which had no data, which is something I need to resolve, but does answer the initial question I had for this post.
data=data%>% 
  mutate(winterfloodfreq = case_when((month %in% c("06") & val >= 2000) ~ 1,
                         TRUE ~ 0))

swan_gtequal95 <- data.frame(data%>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(winterfloodfreq = sum(winterfloodfreq)))



